# no meu código quando eu procuro por variáveis pré inseridadas ele mostra a variavel mais de uma vez

Tags: c#, winforms

por algum motivo assim que eu pesquiso por uma variável no código ele lista a variável só que mais de uma vez se baseando na variável count,e eu não sei o pq isso ocorre

```
int x=0;
int count=0;
string[] item = new string[500];
private void btn_Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (op == true)//op é um boolean que eu usei pra identificar se ele ira inserir variaveis ou pesquisar por elas
            {
                int y = 1;
                count += 1;
                for (x=0;x< y; x++)
                {
                    item[count] = textbox.Text;//aqui ele insere as variaveis em um list box
                    listBox1.Items.Add(item[count]);
                }
            }
            if (op == false)
            {
                for (x = 0; x <= count; x++) {
                    if (textbox.Text == item[count]) {
                        listBox2.Items.Add(item[count]);//aqui era pra ele pesquisar as variaveis
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: pra q um for q só roda 1 vez ?

Answer (score 0):

Troca o count por x, o x que está servindo de index.

Cada array tem um índice, que define qual sua posição na lista, esse índice começa com 0:

```
for (x=0;x< y; x++) { 
   item[x] = textbox.Text; //Passando o x como índice da sua variável, para o texto box pegar ele 
   listBox1.Items.Add(item[x]); 
}
```

No segundo exemplo a mesma coisa:

```
for (x = 0; x <= count; x++) { 
  if (textbox.Text == item[x]) { 
    listBox2.Items.Add(item[x]);//aqui era pra ele pesquisar as variáveis agora pelo indice 
  } 
}
```

Na sua segunda estrutura for por que colocou o count como parâmetro? Ele é zero.